# I18n in rails 3.2: scoping or lazy lookup for translations within controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I try to retrieve some translations in my controllers but the scope will be ignored.
For example:

In UsersController in create action

```
t(".notice")
```

will look for 'notice' at the very first level (i.e. en -> notice) an not at en -> users -> create -> notice.
How can I "activate" the scope so that I don't have to enter

```
t("users.create.notice")
```

everytime.

And why scoping of lazy lookup is activated for views by default but not for controllers?

Using rails 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck unless you upgrade to Rails 4.

The [Rails i18n guide section 3.2.13 on "lazy" lookups](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) says:

> Rails implements a convenient way to look up the locale inside *views*

(Emphasis theirs; lazy lookup functionality is restricted only to views in Rails 3.2)

[This is the commit to Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7082/files) that brought "lazy" lookups into controllers as well.

[The latest Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) as of this writing states that lazy lookups are view-only in Rails 4, but it is not correct anymore as you would be able to use `t(".notice")` in your `UsersController#create` action and get back the expected value.